# Xcode - Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I am trying to upload a new version of my app to iTunes Connect from Xcode.
I keep getting an email saying my app's "`Info.plist` file should contain a NSCalendarsUsageDescription key"

I have already added these strings to my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>microphone use</string>

<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>calendar use</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>photo and video use.</string>
```

But, I still get the email that my `Info.plist` is missing the `NSCalendarsUsageDescription key`

Is there something else I need to add?  Apple's website says I need to "Use the specified APIs to request authorization to use the data or resource."  I am new to coding and don't know what this means!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to write "calendar use". The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data. So provide a better explanation of why your app needs to access this data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the Usage Description Strings to the "Custom iOS Target Properties" rather than only adding them to my info.Plist